# How to tell if a point is part of a line?

Tags: wpf, math, geometry

Given a line define by two points (A,B) how can I tell if another Point (C) is on that line or not, does WPF have a built in function as Im using paths to represent the lines or will I have to write a function. If the latter is true any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Three points are co-linear if the angle they form is 180 degrees. Or stated a different way, the slope of the line segments AB, AC and BC are all equal.

Solving for slopes:  `[AB].y/[AB].x = [AC].y/[AC].x` gives the following nice function:

```
bool AreCollinear(Point A, Point B, Point C) 
{
    double slopesDelta = (A.y - B.y) * (A.x - C.x) - (A.y - C.y) * (A.x - B.x);
    double tolerance = 1e-6;                // substitute for your own tolerance
    return tolerance > Math.Abs(slopesDelta);
}
```

Comment: @StewartStoakes Of course you wouldn't do an *exact* comparison as that would more or less always fail due to rounding errors. Instead of comparing `a == b` you might for example check if the absolute value of the difference of the left hand and right hand term is less than a certain small value: `Math.Abs(a - b) < 1e-6`.

Comment: @Clemens - _absolute_ly valid point ;)  I've updated the code to reflect that!

Comment: Please be aware of the following from the the Remarks section in [Double.Epsilon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx): "If you create a custom algorithm that determines whether two floating-point numbers can be considered equal, we do not recommend that you base your algorithm on the value of the Epsilon constant to establish the acceptable absolute margin of difference for the two values to be considered equal. (Typically, that margin of difference is many times greater than Epsilon.)"

Comment: Continued: "For information about comparing two double-precision floating-point values, see [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) and [Equals(Double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s.aspx)."

Comment: OK I understand epsilons and the double problem. I have encountered it with floats in c++, this caused me many headaches. I am using the function below this was ported from c++ but it used floats instead of doubles. Please can you tell me if this code in your opinion will work ok.     public static bool EqualsWithTolerance (double a, double b)
        {
            return (((b - EPSILON) < a) && (a < (b+EPSILON)));
        }

Comment: public static bool EqualsWithTolerance (double a, double b)
        {
            return (((b - EPSILON) < a) && (a < (b+EPSILON)));
        }

Comment: It depends on the value of `EPSILON`. I guess what @Clemens suggested is that the value of Double.Epsilong is not large enough and that you should use a value of 1e-6 (0.000001) to be safe.

Comment: Ok so I would just set epsilon to 1e-6 (0.000001) and use the function above ?? Thanks guys great help.

Comment: Yeah, you could use the function from my answer, or your `EqualsWithTolerance` version and use a tolerance that makes sense for your particular case. `1e-6` is very large and will definitely work but even smaller values would work ok. So it all depends on the scale of your points. `1e-12` would also work pretty well..

Comment: Of course `1e-6` is just an example value. You need to find a value that makes sense in your use case.

Comment: OK, thanks MikyDinescu Clemens for your help, I will experiment a little with the function and find the appropriate value for EPSILON. Cheers again guys.